# The Jehovah's Witnesses deny that Jesus Christ existed eternally or everlastingly, how do they reconcile this with Micah 5:2?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

Micah 5:2, "But as for you, Bethlehem Ephrathah, Too little to be among the clans of Judah, From you one will go forth for Me to be the ruler of Israel. His goings forth are from long ago, From the days of eternity."

This prophecy is quoted by Matthew at Matthew 2:6, "And you; Bethlehem, land of Judah, Are by no means least among the leaders of Judah; For out of you shall come forth a ruler, Who will Shepherd My people Israel." This is referring to Jesus Christ the Messiah.

The Jehovah's Witnesses agree with me.

> There is no doubt that, from the prophecy of Micah 5:2, Satan the Devil knew where the birth was to take place.... 16. How did Micah 5:2 indicate where the Messiah was to be born?16 Micah 5:2 reads: “And you, O Bethlehem Ephrathah, the one too little to get to be among the thousands of Judah, from you there will come out to me the one who is to become ruler in Israel, whose origin is from early times, from the days of time indefinite.

w81 7/15 pp. 11-16 - The Watchtower—1981"

The prophecy states in the last sentence, "His goings forth/Jesus Christ/Messiah goings forth from long ago, From the days of eternity." The following is from Strong's Lexicon on the word "eternity." Strong's word number 5769 https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h5769/kjv/wlc/0-1/

It's Bible usuage:

Outline of Biblical Usage [?]
long duration, antiquity, futurity, for ever, ever, everlasting, evermore, perpetual, old, ancient, world

ancient time, long time (of past)

(of future)

for ever, always

continuous existence, perpetual

everlasting, indefinite or unending future, eternity

Notice the Jw's word "indefinite" is used with "everlasting, unending future, eternity."

https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/kdo/micah-5.html

shows the point of view of one who interprets Micah 5:2 as proof of the externality of Jesus

So again, how do Jehovah’s Witnesses reconcile this apparent contradiction when you say Jesus Christ did not exist eternally or everlastingly?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133048/discussion-on-question-by-mr-bond-the-jehovahs-witnesses-deny-that-jesus-chris).

Comment: @Ken Graham  It might also be worth pointing out that when one comment asks a person who has previously commented to answer a particular question, then a third party jumps in to answer that question (not addressed to themselves), that stirs up debate, which is wrong. Questions in comments that seek clarification or more info. on the matter in question should be allowed, and only the person to whom the question is addressed should answer. If I'm wrong about that, please correct me.

Comment: @True, but the comments in general got flagged for their growing number; thus it is better to go to chat.

Answer (score 3):

Micah 5:2 proves the opposite of what the OP assumes. Jesus had a beginning "and his going forth is from the beginning, from the days of eternity." Micah 5:2 Douay-Rheims Bible. This is in harmony with Revelation 3:14.

A further reading of Micah reveals, And he shall stand, and shall feed his flock in the strength of Jehovah, in the majesty of the name of Jehovah his God: and they shall abide; for now shall he be great unto the ends of the earth. Micah 5:4 ASV God Almighty does not have a God, thus there no reason to infer that Jesus is Jehovah after reading 5:2.

There is no record of Jesus' followers during his time who understood Micah 5:2, believed that Jesus was “God incarnate.”

Micah 5:2 says that this ruler will be born. The bible has no record of believers of the true God almighty believing that God almighty could be born.

What is clear from the verse is, the Messiah, Jesus Christ had an origin or beginning, the only true God does not have a beginning.

Comment: Going forth (from 5:2) has to do with family descent.  Eternity (from days of eternity) is *olam* which means the vanishing point, the horizon and, when pointing into the past, means without beginning (since the horizon cannot be reached).  Thus Micah 5:2 says that his family descent has no beginning.

Comment: Going forth is often translated origin/origins.  The Messiah would descend from as far back in Bethlehems history as you can go

Comment: Can you link to jw sources to show your answer is portraying the official view of JWs?

Comment: It is an interesting dichotomy to try to understand “days of eternity” if you believe the word Olam means without beginning

Comment: @Alex Balilo Your understanding of Revelation 3:14 is not only in error but supports Micah 5:2. Your using the verse to show Jesus Christ is a created being. The word for "beginning" is "arche." We get are English word "architect" from that word. An architect is the person who draws up makes the plans or designs something. Here is Strong's and Thayer's Lexicon on the word "arche." http://lexiconcordance.com/greek/0746.html This means that Jesus Christ is not only a created being but He is actually the creator. John 1:1-3, Colossians 1:16, Hebrews 1:10 by His Father and here at Revelation 3:14

Comment: @Mr.Bond.Jehovah alone is the Creator. Isaiah 44:24. That is why Jesus himself ascribed creation to his God, Mark 13:19. He will not be the faithful and true witness if his statements are not true. He said that he is the beginning of God's creation. If "God the Word" is the Creator" why is there no record of this God the Word spoken of as the Creator. How many Creator are there. If Jesus is the creator, why did he attributed to God as being the source of his life, John 6:57?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Yes, Isaiah 44:24 says God created all alone and by Himself. John 1:3 says, "All things came into being by Him/Jesus Christ, (this is not talking about God's spoken words), And apart (or without Him/Jesus Christ) NOTHING came into being that has come into being." Reconcile this seemingly contradiction? Prove that  Rev 3:14, means Jesus is created? http://lexiconcordance.com/greek/0746.html Read what Thayer who is a Unitarian said about the word. Explain to me when did the beginning of creation of Jesus from Rev 3:14 happen? Answer my questions first and I will answer yours.

Comment: @Kris I found this on the Hebrew word olam. https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-Hebrew-word-olam-mean Read the first entry and click more to read the rest of what Mr. Brenner stated.

Comment: @Mr.Bond. Jesus never ascribed creation to himself, but to his God., Mark 13:19. He himself knew that his God was the only true God and creator. John 17:3 He pointed to God as the source of his life. John 6:57. There is no record of this God the Word which you insist is the creator, from the beginning. I believe Jesus plain statements. I don't believe equivocation. I believe the plain statements and declaration of God and Jesus.

Comment: @AlexBalilo Oh this is rich! What do you mean Jesus never ascribed creation to himself? His own Father ascribed creation to Him at Hebrews 1:10. "And Thou Lord, in the beginning didst lay the foundation of the earth, And the heavens are the work of Thy hands." Why is this not good enough for you? The Apostle John referenced Jesus as the creator at John 1:1-3. So did Paul at Colossians 1:16. You say you believe the plain statements of Jesus. Ok, John 8:24, "Jesus said you shall die in your sins if you don't believe I am." What do you think He meant?  Read John 8:58 and Exodus 3:14 for a clue.

Comment: @Mr.Bond. There is nothing in Hebrews 1:10 that says Jesus is YHWH the Creator. It was Jesus' God who anointed Jesus.  Hebrews 1:9, ASV Thou hast loved righteousness, and hated iniquity; Therefore God, thy God, hath anointed thee with the oil of gladness above thy fellows. Acts 2:36 ASV Let all the house of Israel therefore know assuredly, that God hath made him both Lord and Christ, this Jesus whom ye crucified. Does Jesus' God have a God over him? Hebrews 1:5 was first applied to Solomon, 2 Samuel 7:14,, are Solomon and Jesus the same?  There is no God the Word as the creator in the bible.

Comment: @AlexBalilo Good ole Acts 2:36 is not saying what you think it's saying. Luke 2:11, for today in the city of David there has been born for you a Savior WHO IS CHRIST THE LORD. Jesus was not made Christ and Lord, He already was.!Read the context of the verses before Acts 2:36. God spoke ahead of the resurrection of Christ. It was, the resurrection that declared that Jesus Christ was already Christ and Lord. Romans 1:3-4 proves it. concerning His Son, who was born of the descendant of David according to the flesh, vs4, WHO WAS DECLARED the Son of God with power by the resurrection from the dead.

Comment: @Mr.Bond. None of the verses you cited proves that Jesus is the creator despite your equivocation. I believe Jesus plain statements. Jesus ascribed creation to God not himself.There is no record of believers of the true God in the bible that believed that the Creator could be born, No record of a God the Word as the Creator. Jesus is a created being, Revelation 3:14, John 3:16. John 6:57.

Answer (score 3):

How do Jehovahs witnesses reconcile their belief that Jesus has not always existed with Micah 5:2 which says his going forth is from long ago, from the days of eternity?

First by pointing to the many different ways a variety of Bible translations render the wording of the final part of Vs2
The New World Translation renders it
“Whose origin is from ancient times,from the days of long ago.”

ESV: whose coming forth is from of old,
from ancient days.

NIV: whose origins are from of old,
from ancient times.”

GNT:whose family line goes back to ancient times.”

I encourage you to go to bible hub to see more

Strongs exhaustive concordance on the meaning of the word translated "eternity" in your opening quotation of Micah 5:2 gives a plethora of words that can express the meaning of ʿôlām.

> long duration, antiquity, futurity, for ever, ever, everlasting, evermore, perpetual, old, ancient, world

It seems important to state also that Jehovah's Witnesses do teach that Jesus existed untold eons of time before any creation of physical universe commenced. We teach that for an unknown amount of time only Jehovah and His Son existed before any creation of spiritual angelic hosts were created.

We also teach that Jehovah brought forth (created) His Son. So there is a moment of origin, a beginning for his life.
This is not the case for Jehovah who alone has existed eternally as the uncreated Almighty God.

If Micah was referencing the pre existence of Jesus and said his origin was from the days of eternity would the fact that Jesus was created eons before any other angels, before any part of the universe exists, before man was created, qualify him as being from days of eternity?   Yes of course it would.

But was Micah alluding to Jesus’ heavenly pre existence? No. Micah is declaring a prophecy regarding the town that would become the birth place of Messiah.  Just two verses later we find Micah saying that This ruler whose origin is from ancient times will “stand and feed his flock in the strength of Jehovah, in the majesty of the name of Jehovah his God”. Micah 5:4 ASV

Jehovah does not have a God.
Jehovah does not have origins.
The eternality of the uncreated Almighty God  cannot have days affixed to it.

Jesus does have a God.
Jesus does have an origin, a beginning.
His days could be numbered though only by his eternally existing Father.

The Messiah   has ancestral roots going all the way back as far as one can go in the history of the city of Bethlehem. These are the days of long ago to which Micah 5:2 is alluding.

Comment: My edits only replaced the word God with Jehovah.               John 1:1 tells us that when the heavens and earth were created the Word was there with God.  Genesis 1 tells us that the heavens and earth were created  before the earth was transformed into a place filled with flora and fauna eventually culminating with God creating Man in His image. Physical creation is what began at the beginning, The beginning is not the moment that Jehovah first brought forth His son.

Comment: Nor is the beginning of John and genesis referring to the time when Jehovah through His son created the angelic hosts who were also on hand to applaud the creation of the heavens and the earth.

Comment: @Mr.Bond. I forgot to tag you